# GCP Compute Engine locked out of ssh

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-18.04

I am having challenges logging  to my compute engine instance,

serial console is giving me the following log.

```
File "/usr/bin/supervisord", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('supervisor==3.3.1', 'console_scripts', 'supervisord')()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 357, in main
options = ServerOptions()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py", line 438, in __init__
existing_directory, default=tempfile.gettempdir())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 275, in gettempdir
tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 217, in _get_default_tempdir
("No usable temporary directory found in %s" % dirlist))
IOError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/'
```

Comment: This article may assist ... https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b

The error seems to say that no temporary directory was found.  Did something change recently in your environment?

Comment: This problem looks like you ran out of space on the root device. Use the serial port console to confirm. You can resize the boot disk in the GCP console.